# Proof or counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let f be a continuous function. Prove or disprove, that $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $x\mapsto x*f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.

I would say, this is true.  My thought: $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{h*f(h)}{h} =\lim\limits_{h\to 0} f(h) = (f \text{ cont.})f(0)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Answer (score 4):

Your thoughts are good, but your presentation is not good !

Let $g(x):=xf(x).$ Then $g(0)=0$, thus

$$ \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h-0}= f(h) \to f(0)$$

as $h \to 0$, since $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: How can i learn to write them mathematical terms so nicely??????